applications opening outside of tigervnc and tightvnc
In a recent Ubuntu 24.04 install, applications are starting on the main display, instead of inside the vncviewer.
From a window manager in gnome-terminal using:
tigervncserver -localhost no :2

or
tightvncserver

for this ~/.vnc/xstartup:
#!/bin/bash

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
exec openbox

I would expect that all of the applications from the openbox menu would start in the vnc session, but the terminal and the chrome browser are starting on the main terminal :0 of the system.
How do I configure vnc to start all applications inside of the vnc session?
Update:
I found the answer here:
Client apps are opened in wrong vnc display
This setting was necessary in xstartup:
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

It would be helpful if someone could tell me why this fixes the problem, as countless xstartup templates on the web do not have this fix.

This question is similar to: Client apps are opened in wrong vnc display. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
